# Portable Makefile for JNI applications

Tags: java, c, makefile, java-native-interface

I have a Java application with a C JNI backend I want to distribute. Distributing the Java part is easy enough -- that's precisely what jars and the JVM are for. Distributing pre-compiled C code is not that easy, and I assume I will have to ask users to build the native library on their own.

At the moment I'm using `ant` to build the Java code and `make` to build the C code. The problem is that I have hard-coded the location of `jni.h` and `jni_md.h` in my Makefile, which is far from portable. I've searched through as many JNI examples as I could find in the world wide web and all of them had a hard-coded path somewhere. If it were any package other than JNI I could happily use something like `pkg-config` to get the right include flags, but as far as I'm aware JNI does not provide any such functionality.

**Question**: how can I write a *portable* makefile that will find the JNI headers and compile my C native code in any* system?

For reference, here are a few options I've considered:

- I could use CMake's [FindJNI](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindJNI.html) function, but I'd rather not since the C code is not that complex and CMake would be a bit of an overkill (plus an extra dependency for the users).
- I could hope that the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set, which I don't expect always to be the case, since (at least in Ubuntu) it's not set by default when you install Java.
- I could use `locate` or `find` to manually find the files and stitch the include flags together, but this feels rather hacky.

*I'm mostly interested in Windows, OSX and mainstream Ubuntu versions with any reasonable modern version of Java.

Comment: what about distributing the correct version of `jni.h` as well in your package?

Comment: @KinCheung thanks for your comment.  Isn't `jni.h` dependent on the specific Java version installed? In my system `jni.h` is in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`, so AFAIK just grabbing that `jni.h` won't necessarily work in systems with any Java other than OpenJDK 8. Isn't this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's portable enough for you to rely on *GNU make* (at least, this is available on most platforms), you could use `JAVA_HOME` and try to determine it yourself in case it is not set like this:

```
ifeq ($(JAVA_HOME),)
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
which = $(shell where $1)
else
which = $(shell which $1)
endif
JAVAC ?= $(realpath $(call which,javac))
JAVA_HOME = $(abspath $(dir $(JAVAC))..)
endif

ifneq ($(JAVA_HOME),)
JNI_INCLUDEDIR ?= $(JAVA_HOME)/include
endif

ifeq ($(JNI_INCLUDEDIR),)
$(error could not determine JNI include dir, try specifying either \
    JAVA_HOME or JNI_INCLUDEDIR)
endif

TARGETTRIPLET := $(shell $(CC) -dumpmachine)
ifeq ($(JNI_PLATFORM),)
ifeq ($(findstring mingw,$(TARGETTRIPLET)),mingw)
JNI_PLATFORM:= win32
else
ifeq ($(findstring linux,$(TARGETTRIPLET)),linux)
JNI_PLATFORM:= linux
# add more checks here
endif
endif
endif

JNI_PLATFORMINCLUDEDIR ?= $(JNI_INCLUDEDIR)/$(JNI_PLATFORM)

$(info JAVA_HOME: $(JAVA_HOME))
$(info JNI_INCLUDEDIR: $(JNI_INCLUDEDIR))
$(info JNI_PLATFORMINCLUDEDIR: $(JNI_PLATFORMINCLUDEDIR))

all:
    @:

.PHONY: all
```

example outputs:

```
> make
JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
JNI_INCLUDEDIR: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include
JNI_PLATFORMINCLUDEDIR: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include/linux

> make JAVA_HOME=/foo/bar
JAVA_HOME: /foo/bar
JNI_INCLUDEDIR: /foo/bar/include
JNI_PLATFORMINCLUDEDIR: /foo/bar/include/linux

> make JNI_INCLUDEDIR=/foo/bar
JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
JNI_INCLUDEDIR: /foo/bar
JNI_PLATFORMINCLUDEDIR: /foo/bar/linux

> make JNI_PLATFORM=amigaos
JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64
JNI_INCLUDEDIR: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include
JNI_PLATFORMINCLUDEDIR: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/include/amigaos
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @FelixPalmen. How about `jni_md.h`? That's usually in an OS-dependent subfolder of `${JNI_INCLUDEDIR}`. Is there a way to find and include subfolders inside `${JNI_INCLUDEDIR}`?

Comment: That's a bit tricky, the best way would be to determine it based on the output of `$(CC) -dumpmachine` ... I'll add a simple example

Comment: Looks good, and it did the trick in my Ubuntu 16.04. I'll try it out in a Windows machine and if it works I'll mark the answer as correct.

Comment: For the record: I tried and it did work as expected. Answer accepted, thanks!